# Umbraco PartialView Macros and @helper

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

This has been driving me crazy for about 3 hours now.  We upgraded from Umbraco 4 to Umbraco 7 and now our site menus are broken.  We used to use a script that traversed the nodes and created a CSS menu system.

So I have started reading up on the new stuff and I just can't even get a @helper or @functions block to work.  The script is now using a PartialView Macro that uses a parameter called MenuNode that is the Node I want to traverse down.

Here's the code that works:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@{
var menuNode1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Model.MacroParameters["MenuNode"])? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(Model.MacroParameters["MenuNode"]);
}

<h1>@menuNode1</h1>
```

As soon as I try to add a @helper or @functions like in the Navigation PartialView example provided in Umbraco it stops working.  Here is what breaks it.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@{
    var menuNode1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Model.MacroParameters["MenuNode"])? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(Model.MacroParameters["MenuNode"]);
}

@TestHelper(menuNode1)

@helper TestHelper(var testvalue)
{
    <h1>@testvalue</h1>
}
```

Can anyone point me at what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  It was because I was using var in the @helper parameter list, changed to dynamic and it worked fine.